# Visualizing kmodes clusters

Tags: clustering, data-visualization, categorical-data

I am working on cluster analysis of a completely categorical data set using package `klaR` and function `kmodes`. A sample of the data is available on [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0yx8rpw1yktxn96/sample.csv?dl=0). Just cross the sign-up notification dropbox will show when link opens.

The code to do the clustering was simple enough.

```
require(klaR)    
c1 <- kmodes(df, 5, 5, weighted = FALSE)
```

My questions are:

1. How do I visualize these clusters? I have done simple plots in the past with k-means clusters: `plotcluster(data, clus$cluster)`. When I try this here, I get:

   ```
    Error: is.numeric(x) || is.logical(x) is not TRUE
   ```
2. How do I decide optimal number of clusters? I've read through [Cluster analysis in R: determine the optimal number of clusters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376075/cluster-analysis-in-r-determine-the-optimal-number-of-clusters) on Stack Overflow, but there is no mention of categorical variables anywhere and I could not understand which of the several methods discussed by the author will be applicable in my case.

Comment: I'll suggest use clusplot. `library("cluster"); clusplot(bob3, clus$cluster, color=TRUE, shade=TRUE, labels=2, lines=0)`.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need the command `plot(data, col=clus\$cluster)` instead. Or rather just `plot(data[,c(j,l)], col=clus$cluster)`. This will give the graphs of a group of columns with respect to the clusters. About optimal number of clusters, I would just try different number of clusters starting from 2 and try to see from there how good I can do.